# Xamarin Android HttpClient keep alive not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.android, dotnet-httpclient

I am using Xamarin.Android with a PCL. In my PCL, I use a HttpClient to Get or Post HTTP requests to an API.
I want to use the same instance of my HttpClient for multiple HTTP requests, and to use the keep-alive.

Here is my code for test :

```
HttpClient c = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate });
c.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15);
c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", bufferItem.m_sAutorisationBasic);
c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    HttpRequestMessage t = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(bufferItem.m_sURL));
    HttpResponseMessage r = await c.SendAsync(t);
}
```

Unfortunately, sniffing there requests using the Android Application "Packet Capture" demonstrates that keep-alive is not working... As shown on the picture below, a TCP stream manage only one HTTP request :

[image]

Thanks to [this very interesting post](https://mttkay.github.io/blog/2013/03/02/herding-http-requests-or-why-your-keep-alive-connection-may-be-dead/) I have been able to get a real keep-alive working, but only for a "HEAD" request (I need it working for GET and POST request).
When I use the code above, and replace the **HttpMethod.Get** by **HttpMethod.Head**, I got keep-alive working, as shown below :

[image]

[The post](https://mttkay.github.io/blog/2013/03/02/herding-http-requests-or-why-your-keep-alive-connection-may-be-dead/) specifies that you need to "fully consume the response payload", that mean "reading bytes from the input stream until hitting the EOS byte", to get keep-alive working on Android.

Unfortunately, I don't understand what should I do to "fully consume my response"...

I use this code to consume my HttpResponseMessage, and keep-alive is not working :

```
HttpResponseMessage r = await c.SendAsync(t);
string content = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Anyone can help with that ? What am I doing wrong please ?